# keycloak‘s redirect_uri=x.x.x.x:0

Tags: java

I use SpringBoot,the jar was run on port 8081.But int the console of keyclock the message is  that port is 0;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H4c0.png)

Comment: it would be helpful if you'll elaborate in details how to reproduce this scenario. Don't be afraid to add details such as how did you get the SpringBoot configuration, on which OS you are working on, etc

Comment: Please put additional information and clarify with screen shot and other detail as applicable